# CSS Animation Keep Jumping Back to First Image

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to build a little CSS fade-in image and everything working except for the fact that once everything has faded in the slides are jumping back to the first image instead of staying on the fourth and final side.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;   
}
li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
}
img{
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation: xfade 16s 0s 1;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation: xfade 16s 4s 1;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation: xfade 16s 8s 1;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  animation: xfade 16s 12s 1;
}
@keyframes xfade{
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-4.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-2.jpg" /></li>    
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-1.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your animation with a few things noted in the source code.
My fix is a reversed thinking of yours. I follow the order of layer rendering. You may have a reference.

- set a initial value for your li to avoid [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)
- image order is reversed since for elements with position absolute, the last one will be the top most element without explicitly set the z-index.
- time is shortened for a fast testing result
- [added animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode): forwards;

> added animation-fill-mode: forwards; || The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution.

```css
      ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;   
}
li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;

  /* initial, or it will actually flash or so called FOUC. begin from nothing */
  opacity: 0;
}
img{
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation: xfade 1.6s 1.6s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation: xfade 1.6s 0.8s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation: xfade 1.6s 0.4s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  animation: xfade 1.6s 0s 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes xfade{
  17% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }

  /* animation-fill-mode: forwards; "last keyframe encountered is 100% or to" */
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-2.jpg" /></li>    
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-3.jpg" /></li>

  <!-- the last one is the most toppest layer rendered -->
  <li><img title="" alt="" src="https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/homepage/images/home-slide-4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```